# Java MVC with File Input/Output

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, file-io, input

I am creating a program using MVC pattern in java... However Im very confused on how to properly perform file input.

For example, should I perform all file input in MAIN? ..I tried but its getting messy, and Im not sure if there is a "uniform" way of performing file input for MVC pattern.  This is for an OOP assignment btw. Thank you.

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't do any I/O in `main`, but as to any other questions, this is so broad there's no way to make any sensible recommendations.

Comment: thank you for your comment i understand IO should not go in main now and i have made sensible advancements. godspeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a theoretical question, the  answer would be theoretical.

MVC means Model View Controller

```
Model - Model represents the layer that is closely related to data. Say if you want to persist a Employee object, you have a Employee POJO carrying the Employee data.

View - View represents the visualization of the data that model contains.

Controller - Controller acts on both Model and view. It controls the data flow into model object and updates the view whenever data changes. It keeps View and Model separate.
```

In your case, File Input process - what do you mean by that? A File is send as input and you need to persist the file in your database?

This is **not** a good use case for showing MVC pattern. yet..for your understanding

```
View - you can have a File Upload page

Controller - The class that route the control from view to a Java class that performs File Read, and performs business logic on the input file

Model - A class that has database connection setup, and has a method that accepts the final formatted File and store to the database.
```

*More experienced folks, correct me if you feel that way*

Comment: thank you for your post it helped alot. godspeed.